# ASP.NET MVC Valdiation without using Data Annotations?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Since I don't really prefer working with partial views, I've successfully been able to use just one ViewModel for displaying a form the way I want, and submitting the data works fine.

The issue is the validation however since, I have two virtual properties in the database that
I don't think that I'm actually able to use data annotations on them.

Here's the productviewmodel that I'm using.

```
 public class ProductViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description1 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description2 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description3 { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Image { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double? Weight { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string SelectedCategory { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }

    public string SelectedProductStatus { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProductStatuses { get; set; }


    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Relase Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    //Note that I'm using these virtual properties so that I don't have to use
    //different viewmodels in partial views.
    public virtual Stock Stock { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Rating> Rating { get; set; }
    public virtual Discount Discount { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }  
    }
```

And here is the stock view:

```
@model GUI.Models.ProductViewModel

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Stock";
 }

<h2>Stock</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateStock","Product", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Stock for @Model.Name</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Quantity in Stock", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            //Note that is is how I use the productviewModel to display and 
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Stock.Quantity)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Stock.Quantity)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Delivery Date for Stock (yyyy/mm/dd)", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Stock.DeliveryDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Stock.DeliveryDate)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" onclick="validate()"/>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 }

  <div>
   @Html.ActionLink((HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(" &laquo;") + "Back to Products"), "Index", "Product", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-large" })
```

This is the controller action that I'm calling when submitting the form.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateStock(Guid id, ProductViewModel model)
    {
        int quantity = (int)model.Stock.Quantity;
        DateTime deliveryDate = Convert.ToDateTime(model.Stock.DeliveryDate);

        _manager.UpdateProductStock(id, quantity, deliveryDate);          
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Since I'm not sure if I'm able to use data annotations or not, I have to make sure that quantity field is only an integer number, and that the deliverydate is in date format.

Do I have to write a lot of javascript validation to solve this problem? And if so, how do 
I make sure that controller action doesn't run unless the data is valid without using data
annotation?

Or is there another and simpler way for me to handle this validation issue?

Any thoughts, code examples and explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Without using Data Annotations, it is also possible validate your model in server side and add alerts to `ModelState` and show them in view.

Second approach is to use clientside validations. One of them is [Jquery Validation Engine](https://plugins.jquery.com/validationengine/). There are a lot of samples [here](http://posabsolute.github.io/jQuery-Validation-Engine/)

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use virtual properties and DataAnnotations together. [Here is an example using lazy loading with EF](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-6)

UPDATE:

The gist of the post is:

```
public virtual Stock Stock { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Rating> Rating { get; set; }
public virtual Discount Discount { get; set; }
public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
```

Now in your objects:

```
public class Stock 
{
    [Display(Name = "My property name"]
    public virtual string SomeProperty {get;set;)

    //all the properties
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback. This place is just great.

Nested Viewmodels seemed to do the trick for me. Got great tips from a buddy of mine.
I added this field in my ProductViewModel:

```
public StockViewModel StockViewModel { get; set; }
```

And I added a StockViewModel:

```
public class StockViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Only integer numbers are allowed")]
    public int? Quantity { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? DeliveryDate { get; set; }
}
```

And I made following changes in the Stock Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Stock(Guid id)
    {
        Product product = _productRepository.GetById(id);

        var productViewModel = new ProductViewModel
        {
            Id = product.Id,
            Name = product.Name,

            StockViewModel = new StockViewModel { Id = product.Stock.Id, DeliveryDate = product.Stock.DeliveryDate, Quantity = product.Stock.Quantity }
        };


        return View(productViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateStock(Guid id, ProductViewModel model)
    {

        int quantity = (int)model.StockViewModel.Quantity;
        DateTime deliveryDate = Convert.ToDateTime(model.StockViewModel.DeliveryDate);

        _manager.UpdateProductStock(id, quantity, deliveryDate);          
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

And then I made these changes in the stock view:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Quantity in Stock", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            //Note the changes here 
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StockViewModel.Quantity)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StockViewModel.Quantity)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Delivery Date for Stock (yyyy/mm/dd)", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
             //Note the changes here!
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StockViewModel.DeliveryDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StockViewModel.DeliveryDate)
        </div>
    </div>
```